# Why use 'undefined' as 2nd parameter in a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I saw this scope encapsulation, with the undefined value as 2nd parameter in the jQUery UI source code https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.button.js .As I'm writing a jquery ui plugin, I'm wondering what is the benefit to set undefined in parameter ?

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
//...
}( jQuery);
```

Comment: Good question! I've been wondering about this as well.

Comment: It is used to make sure that undefined really mean undefined i.e. if by mistake somewhere in the code undefined = abc( is assigned a value) then it will render all those if(something === undefined) useless because then you'll be comparing against abc and not undefined. This way, undefined is truly undefined because when invoked (function ($, undefined){...}(jQuery);' $ is assigned jQuery but undefined is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done, to have a pointer to the "real" `undefined` value.

In general, in JavaScript you can even modify the value stored under `undefined`, which in turn breaks many use cases for it.

```
undefined = 'abc';
var obj = { prop: 'abc' };

if ( obj.prop == undefined ) {
  // do something
  // this is actually called despite the fact, that the property is set!
}
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments by @Christoph this also helps in reducing the code size, when using minifiers. Here the local `undefined` is treated as a usual variable, which can be minified to, e.g., `a` possibly and thus reducing the code size.

Comment: This is why you use `typeof obj.prop === 'undefined'`.

Comment: htm5 defines it as readonly. Most modern browsers comply to that. The more relevant reason is that as a variablename it can be minified to a single letter.

Comment: @DJDavid98 you can still overwrite `undefined` in older browsers.

Comment: This is not entirely correct as it depends on the implementation of ECMA Script and not "HTML5" (starting from ECMAScript 5 undefined is read only).

Answer (score 1):

It creates a local copy of undefined variable for your function which point to actual undefined, so if someone has changed the  value of undefined globally , it will not effect your code.

How it works is , as you are not passing the second parameter in your self executing function. So value of undefined variable will be actually undefined.